# Yield a mongoose result from a loop in Koa.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, koa

I'm using Koa.js with Mongoose.js. There is a collection in my mongo named css. Which have following schema:

```
_id
css_name
css_value
```

I have an array containing a huge list like:

```
var list = ['font-color', 'back-color', 'font-family', 'back-image', 'back-repeat', ... ];
```

Now I've declared a mongoose model named css and executing a loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   console.log(yield css.findOne({css_name: list[i]}).exec());
}
```

If I execute the code above it gives null in the console. Whenever I omit the loop, it works perfectly:

```
//for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   console.log(yield css.findOne({css_name: 'font-color'}).exec());
//}
```

So the problem is with the loop. Can anyone suggest a better working way to fetch all the values from a loop using the mongoose model?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a problem with your code to be honest, it should work, and if you see `null` as result is because the query didn't return any document, try `mongoose.set('debug', true)` and execute the queries yourself. Anyway, if you just need all results at once, just use `co-each` as follow:

```
var each = require('co-each')

var styles = ['font-color', 'back-color', 'font-family', 'back-image', 'back-repeat']

// executed in parallel
var results = yield each(styles, function *getStyle(style) {
  return yield css.findOne({ css_name: style }).exec()
})

console.log(results)
```